# How can I have multiple Divs stack on top of each other using Float and not absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I'm rewriting everything and moving away from absolute positions and instead using floats to position things the way I want them.

The question now is how can I float multiple divs on top of each other? The user will be able to switch between these divs somehow.

Thanks

Edit: The reason I'm moving away from absolute position is that I want my div to still be a child of its parent. i.e. if my div gets extended I want the parent div to get extended also.

Comment: You mean overlap? You could use a negative margin-left for elements after the first...

Comment: If "on top" means "overlapping" and the user is somehow switching between the divs such that only one is actually visible at a time wouldn't you just set all but the current to `display:none`?

Comment: nn... your answer makes perfect sense. The user can see one div at a time anyways, if I change the display from none to block and vice versa my problem is solved. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Parent divs don't consider child floating elements, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/4JgSE/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

float does not overlap with other floated objects in the same container.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JKYnF/) for an example of three successive floated objects to see how they don't overlap.

If you want objects to overlap, you will want/need to use absolute positioning.  You can use positioning relative to the parent object by setting the parent to `position:relative;` and the child to `position: absolute;`.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DtTwe/) for an example of overlaping objects with absolute positioning relative to the parent.

If, you're trying to only have one of these objects actually display at a time, then just set the non-displayed objects to `display: none` and they will take no space in the page layout.  You won't need to use float or absolute positioning.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use position: absolute; is that I want the div to still be a child of its parent; i.e. if the size of my div expands I want the parent div to expand, too.

Comment: @Roozbeh15 - If you put that in your question to describe the REAL problem you're trying to solve, then perhaps you might get an answer to your real question.  I'd suggest you edit your question now to describe what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @Roozbeh15 - in addition, float doesn't cause the parent to size to it either so there are two reasons why float won't solve your problem as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xH6Kb/.

Comment: @Roozbeh15 - added an option to my answer for `display: none` for the non-visible objects.

Comment: float keeps the parent child relationship of divs. So, if your inner div expands the parent will expand with it! using absolute positioning will destroy the parent/child relationship between the divs.

Comment: @Roozbeh15 - float on a child does not size the parent to fit.  You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xH6Kb/ where the parent is the black bordered, blue background object and the floated child objects are the red boxes.  The parent is full width (the default for divs) and gets none of it's height from the child objects.

Comment: I just saw your link. The position of the container needs to be absolute.

Comment: @Roozbeh15 - OK, once again, you're leaving out all the important aspects of your question.  Next time you ask a question, please ask the real question and include all relevant requirements.  Anyway, glad you found a solution this time.

Comment: Well, that wasn't part of my problem. I already had the expanding of parent/child div working fine. I just wanted a solution for putting divs on top of each other while using "float". Thanks for the help, anyway!

Comment: @Roozbeh15 - it sounds like you don't understand that until you give people the whole picture of what you're trying to do and why, we can't offer you the best solutions.  The fact that your container was position:absolute, affects the layout and affects your requirement that the parent shrinkwrap to the children which affects which solutions are OK with you.  It is relevant info if you want people to come up with solutions that will work for you.

Comment: I completely understand your point of view. But, I don't think that the whole picture is always necessary in order to get the answer for a small part. I will try to be more thorough in my future questions and explain all related parts though. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @Roozbeh15 I just ran across this and wanted to thank you for remaining so civil and genuinely nice. You are an asset to the community!

Answer (score 5):

I'm inexperienced in CSS selectors, but I'm sure you can find something that works better than naming each class specifically:

http://jsfiddle.net/aJqb2/

## HTML:

```
<div class="over1"></div>
<div class="over2"></div>
<div class="over3"></div>
```

## CSS:

```
div{
    height:50px;
    width:150px;

    float:left;
}
.over1{
    background-color:blue;
}
.over2{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    background-color:green;
}
.over3{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you are going to have users switch between the DIVs without using JavaScript.

Perhaps, leave the first div with the default static layout and display none for the others.  Use JavaScript to show only one div at a time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `float: left;`, but personally I find it easier to use `display: inline-block;` instead.

Comment: float doesn't overlap with other float object in the same container.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JKYnF/) for an example of three floated objects in a row.